# Why is my direction so inaccurate for my normalized vector?

Tags: java, vector, 2d, game-physics

I'm designing a game and have gotten a lot of it working well. My one qualm is that my current method for moving a sprite from one point to another works well... but the direction is somewhat inaccurate. It wouldn't be so bad if the sprite didn't "snap" into place at the end of its path.

Is there any suggestion someone could make to either
a) Help improve the accuracy of my direction
b) Help make the sprite come into place more gently

Here is my code for calculating a movement from point A to B:

```
if (!mMoving) {
        mMoving = true;
        mVecStart = new Vec(mPos.getX(),mPos.getY());
        mVecEnd = new Vec(target.getX(), target.getY());

        mDistanceToDestination = Vec.distanceBetween(mVecEnd, mVecStart);

        mDirection = mVecStart.directionTo(mVecEnd, mDistanceToDestination);

        mVelocityX = mDirection.mDX * mSpeed;
        mVelocityY = mDirection.mDY * mSpeed;
    }


    if (mMoving == true) {
        // Move along the x and y axis at given velocity, scaled by deltaTime.
        this.mPos.x += mVelocityX * deltaTime;
        this.mPos.y += mVelocityY * deltaTime;

        // If the distance traveled exceeds the original distance computed, snap the sprite
        // into place immediately.
        if (mMoving && Vec.distanceBetween(mVecStart, new Vec(this.mPos.x, this.mPos.y))
                >= mDistanceToDestination) {
            this.mPos.x = (int) target.getX();
            this.mPos.y = (int) target.getY();
            mMoving = false;
            mMoveComplete = true;
        }
    }
```

Here is how direction is being calculated:

```
public Vec directionTo(Vec vecEnd, double distance) {

    return new Vec((vecEnd.mDX - this.mDX) / distance,
            ((vecEnd.mDY - this.mDY) / distance));
}
```

Comment: Your direction function makes no sense to me.  It should either have start and end point arguments or a single vector.  The normalization should not be passed in; it should be calculated from the vector itself.  Either the vector is wrong or the magnitude is incorrect.  You don't show what the test case is or the answer you get.  Both would help in figuring out what you did wrong.  A debugger would tell you faster than asking here.

Answer (score 1):

You calculate the unit vector for a given vector by dividing each component by its magnitude.

Here's how I'd calculate the magnitude of a planar vector in a rectangular coordinate system:

```
package vector;

import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

/**
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 11/26/2016.
 * @link
 */
public class VectorUtils {

    public static double magnitude(Point2D beg, Point2D end) {
        double magnitude = 0.0;
        if ((beg != null) && (end != null)) {
            double dx = Math.abs(end.getX()-beg.getX());
            double dy = Math.abs(end.getY()-beg.getY());
            if ((dx == 0.0) && (dy == 0.0)) {
                magnitude = 0.0;
            } else {
                if (dx > dy) {
                    double r = dy/dx;
                    magnitude = dx*Math.sqrt(1.0+r*r);
                } else {
                    double r = dx/dy;
                    magnitude = dy*Math.sqrt(1.0+r*r);
                }
            }
        }
        return magnitude;
    }
}
```

You should learn how to use Junit to test your classes.  You'll spend less time in a debugger or scratching your head over defects:

```
package vector;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

/**
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 11/26/2016.
 * @link
 */
public class VectorUtilsTest {

    public static final double TOLERANCE = 1.0E-16;

    @Test
    public void testMagnitude_NullArguments() {
        // setup
        Point2D beg = null;
        Point2D end = null;
        // exercise and assert
        Assert.assertEquals(0.0, VectorUtils.magnitude(beg, end), TOLERANCE);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMagnitude_ZeroVector() {
        // setup
        Point2D beg = new Point2D.Double(0.0, 0.0);
        Point2D end = new Point2D.Double(0.0, 0.0);
        // exercise and assert
        Assert.assertEquals(0.0, VectorUtils.magnitude(beg, end), TOLERANCE);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMagnitude_UnitX() {
        // setup
        Point2D beg = new Point2D.Double(0.0, 0.0);
        Point2D end = new Point2D.Double(2.0, 0.0);
        // exercise and assert
        Assert.assertEquals(2.0, VectorUtils.magnitude(beg, end), TOLERANCE);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMagnitude_UnitY() {
        // setup
        Point2D beg = new Point2D.Double(0.0, 0.0);
        Point2D end = new Point2D.Double(0.0, 2.0);
        // exercise and assert
        Assert.assertEquals(2.0, VectorUtils.magnitude(beg, end), TOLERANCE);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMagnitude() {
        // setup
        Point2D beg = new Point2D.Double(0.0, 0.0);
        Point2D end = new Point2D.Double(1.0, 1.0);
        // exercise and assert
        Assert.assertEquals(Math.sqrt(2.0), VectorUtils.magnitude(beg, end), TOLERANCE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the unit test lesson, it benefits me also.And haha for the bold profil description.